# PostgreSQLにてSQLログを出力して確認する方法

Tags: postgresql

[データベースに登録できません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/94722/%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ab%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/94842#94842)
の質問で、PostgreSQLにてSQLログを出力して確認する方法を行いたいのですが、コマンドの箇所で苦戦しています。

下記のサイトを参考に再起動までは行えたのですが、肝心のコマンドの入力が行えません。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

参考サイト
https://bsofsys.com/2023/01/05/postgresql-log/

[image: コマンド]

Answer (score 1):

`alter` コマンドは SQL が解釈するコマンドなので、コマンドプロンプト上で実行しても認識されません (Windows のコマンドではないため)。

参照している記事では以下の通り `psql` で PostgreSQL に接続した状態で `alter` コマンドを実行しています。

> `psql` にて以下のコマンドを実行します。
>
> ```
> alter database sampledb set log_statement = 'all’;
> ```

psql での接続方法は以下の記事等を参照してみてください。

[PostgreSQLへの接続と切断](https://www.javadrive.jp/postgresql/connect/index2.html)

> psql を使って PostgreSQL へ接続するには次のように実行します。(実際には PostgreSQL で作成済みの指定したータベースに接続します)。
>
> ```
> psql -h ホスト名 -p ポート番号 -U ロール名 -d データベース名
> ```

Answer (score 0):

指定のサイトは
psql でログインしている事が前提ですね。