# pgAdminで作成したテーブルにEclipseから登録した際の確認方法

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, spring-boot

下記の質問の流れから新しいスレッドを立てさせていただきます。
[データベースに登録できません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/94722/%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ab%e7%99%bb%e9%8c%b2%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/94871?noredirect=1#comment108529_94871)

Spring Framework 超入門 という参考書を参考にJava Spring bootの勉強をしているのですが
Eclipseで作成したQuizファイルのQuizApplicationからpgAdminで作成したquizdb/schemas/public/tableを右クリックして作成したQuizテーブルにクイズの問題を登録するコードをEclipseのQuizファイルのQuizApplicationを右クリックして実行の箇所のspring boot アプリケーションをクリックして実行を行いましたが、pgAdminのQuizテーブルで登録したクイズを確認しようとするためにquizdb/schemas/public/table/quizを右クリックして下から二番目にある、QueryToolをクリックして中身を確認しようとしたのですが、登録されたクイズを確認できませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

対してEclipseからQuiz.Applicationというクイズの登録を行うファイルをSpringboot実行によって、実行させますと、下記の実行結果が得られました。

```
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:55.489+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.quiz.QuizApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:55.540+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:55.540+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.034+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.078+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 1 JDBC repository interfaces.
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.543+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.553+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.553+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.604+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.604+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1063 ms
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.700+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.859+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7d1ba0f2
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.860+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:56.991+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:57.391+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-05-20T03:18:57.398+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.quiz.QuizApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started QuizApplication in 2.243 seconds (process running for 3.056)
--- 全件取得開始 ----
Quiz(id=1, question=「Spring」はフレームワークですか？, answer=true, author=登録太郎)
Quiz(id=2, question=「Spring MVC」はバッチ処理機能を提供しますか？, answer=false, author=登録太郎)
--- 全件取得完了 ---
```

実行結果を確認しますと登録されているように見えます。
pgAdminで確認できなくても学習を進めても大丈夫でしょうか？

・QuizApplication.java

```
package com.example.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.quiz.entity.Quiz;
import com.example.quiz.repository.QuizRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QuizApplication {
    /** 起動メソッド */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizApplication.class, args)
        .getBean(QuizApplication.class).execute();
    }
    /** 注入 */
    @Autowired
    QuizRepository repository;
    /** 実行メソッド */
    private void execute() {
        //登録処理
        //setup();
        //全件取得
        showList();
        //１件取得
        //showOne();
        //更新処理
        //updateQuiz();
        //削除処理
        //deleteQuiz();
    }
    /** === クイズを２件登録します === */
    private void setup() {
        //エンティティ生成
        Quiz quiz1 = new Quiz(null, "「Spring」はフレームワークですか？", true, "登録太郎");
        //登録実行
        quiz1 = repository.save(quiz1);
        //登録確認
        System.out.println("登録したデータは、" + quiz1 + "です。");
        //エンティティ生成
        Quiz quiz2 = new Quiz(null, "「Spring MVC」はバッチ処理機能を提供しますか？", false, "登録太郎");
        //登録実行
        quiz2 = repository.save(quiz2);
        //登録確認
        System.out.println("登録したデータは、" + quiz2 + "です。");
    }
    
    /** === 前権取得 === */
    private void showList() {
        System.out.println("--- 全件取得開始 ----");
        // リポジトリを仕様して前権取得を実施、結果を取得
        Iterable<Quiz> quizzes = repository.findAll();
        for (Quiz quiz : quizzes) {
            System.out.println(quiz);
        }
        System.out.println("--- 全件取得完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === １件取得 === */
    private void showOne() {
        System.out.println("--- 1件取得開始 ---");
        //リポジトリを使用して１件取得を実施、結果を取得(戻り値はOptional)
        Optional<Quiz> quizOpt = repository.findById(1);
        //値存在チェック
        if (quizOpt.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(quizOpt.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("該当する問題が存在しません・・・");
        }
        System.out.println("--- １件取得完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === 更新処理 === */
    private void updateQuiz() {
        System.out.println("--- 更新処理開始 ---");
        //更新したいエンティティを生成する
        Quiz quiz1 = new Quiz(1, "「スプリング」はフレームワークですか？", true, "変更タロウ");
        //更新実行
        quiz1 = repository.save(quiz1);
        //更新確認
        System.out.println("更新したデータは、" + quiz1 + "です。");
        System.out.println("--- 更新処理完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === 削除処理 === */
    private void deleteQuiz() {
        System.out.println("--- 削除処理開始 ---");
        // 削除実行
        repository.deleteById(4);
        System.out.println("--- 削除処理完了 ---");
    }
    
    @RestController
    public class MyController {

        @Autowired
        private QuizRepository quizRepository;

        @GetMapping
        List<Quiz> index() {
            Iterable<Quiz> quizList = quizRepository.findAll();
            ArrayList<Quiz> result = new ArrayList<>();
            quizList.forEach(result::add);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

実行環境
Eclipse　日本語版2022年度
Java11
Postgres15

Comment: "pgAdminに登録されているかを確認しようとしているのですが、pgAdminのQuizテーブルの中を確認するものの" これは具体的にどういうコマンドを実行した/どういう画面操作を行ったのですか？質問者の操作が起因の問題なので、こういった部分の説明を端折ると解決に至りません。

Comment: 指摘箇所を修正してみたのですが、どうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueryTool`画面を開いた状態であれば、

> `select * from quiz`

と入力し、実行(▶︎アイコン)することで、レコードが表示されないでしょうか?

Comment: 表示されました！ありがとうございます！！！